# Copy Binaries In Lambda /tmp Folder While Deploying The Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, ephemeral-storage

I am trying to run a headless Chrome service on lambda using NodeJS.
My code works fine but it is complaining about the chrome binaries as the lambda does not have them.

If I try to ship the binaries in the zip package,the maximum zip size for lambda reaches (which I think is 250MB with a hard limit)

I read the documentation and a few articles and I got to know that we can make use of the `ephemeral storage` where we can store additional files in `/tmp/` directory.

My problem is - **How to copy the chrome binaries in the `/tmp/` folder WHILE DEPLOYING the lambda (so it becomes a one-time process)**

I don't want to execute this process during the lambda execution as it will become an unnecessary overhead.

I have heard of using a helper lambda as a resource to the main lambda function but I am not sure if it is possible.

I tried a serverless configuration for the same as follows but it doesn't work -

```
resources:
    CopyChromeBinaries:
        Type: Custom::CopyChromeBinaries
        Properties:
            ServiceToken: arn:aws:lambda:region:ACCOUNT_ID:function:CopyChromeBinaries
```

Please let me know if I have missed anything or if more information is required

Comment: As you said `/tmp` just is a ephemeral storage, it is designed to save some data while your lambda function is executing, this directory can be clear at some point. For chrome binary, you have to use another options, ex: Lambda Layer, store the bin in s3 bucket, or docker-zing your lambda function to an image.

Comment: @hoangdv thanks for the ideas. I tried using layers to separate out the node_modules and binaries in separate layers. However the 250MB hard limit seems to be applicable to the lambda and all the layers used in the lambda. So it seems by one way or other I will end up getting the limit errors. The node_modules are around 130MB and binaries are 370MB unzipped so it's too big for lambda to handle it seems

Comment: Have you tried using [EFS with Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/)?  Since the binaries you're storing there would be primarily read only you shouldn't have to worry about many simultaneous Lambda instances running.